# pandas groupby then merge as one row with new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['China','China', 'India', 'India', 'America', 
    'Japan', 'China', 'India'],
    'Year': ['2001', '2002', '2001', '2002', '2001', '2001', '1999', '1999'],
    'Income':[10000, 10000, 5000, 5002, 40000, 50000, 8000, 5000],
    'Age':[5000, 4321, 1234, 4010, 250, 250, 4500, 4321]})

print(df)
```

```
   Country  Year  Income   Age
0    China  2001   10000  5000
1    China  2002   10000  4321
2    India  2001    5000  1234
3    India  2002    5002  4010
4  America  2001   40000   250
5    Japan  2001   50000   250
6    China  1999    8000  4500
7    India  1999    5000  4321
```

this is the expected result

```
   Country   Income-2000, Income-2001, Income-2002 
0    China  8000   10000  10000  
1    India  5000    5000  5002
4  America  n/a   40000  n/a
5    Japan  n/a   50000   n/a
```

is there any simple way to get this?
or the way is loop it like this then merge as a new datafram?

```
for index,data in df.groupby('Country'):
    print(index)
    print(data)
```

Comment: try :  `table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Country'], columns=['Year'])
 `, should close to what you want.

Comment: if works with above sample data, but the actual data is very big and a lot of other columns, i can't make sure whether this is caused by some dirty data, i got this error:
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate